# How to get rid off age in days error in JavaScript. getting same age difference for two continue dates of different months

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following JavaScript function (script) to calculate age in days. It gives the same age in days for the last day of a month and for the first day of the next month. E.g. it gives age 1400 days for both 31/05/2016 and 01/06/2016. Could anyone help me to find and resolve the issue? Thanks in advance.

```
function ageindays(birthDate){

  var yearThen = parseInt(birthDate.substring(0,4), 10);
  var monthThen = parseInt(birthDate.substring(5,7), 10);
  var dayThen = parseInt(birthDate.substring(8,10), 10);
  var today = new Date();
  var birthday = new Date(yearThen, monthThen, dayThen);

  var differenceInMilisecond = today.valueOf() - birthday.valueOf();
  var diffindays = differenceInMilisecond/86400000

  console.log(diffindays);
}

console.log("First date calculation")
ageindays("2016-06-01")
console.log("Next date calculation")
ageindays("2016-05-31")
```

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in how dates are enumerated in javascript. Months are enumerated 0-11, which means that you have to shift the month with 1 to get a decent response.

When the date then does not exist: 31st of June does not exist, it just flows over into July: July first.

So the two sample dates:

- 2016-05-31 parsed as above becomes: 2016-06-31 which is 2016-07-01 in human
- 2016-06-01 parsed as above becomes: 2016-07-01 in human